# get record with at least one associated object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid, model-associations

I have the following schema in *mongoid*:

> User has many tasks - has_many :tasks
>
> Task belongs to user - belongs_to :user

How can I get only 10 first users with at least one task?

Something like this:

```
User.where(:tasks.ne => [] ).limit(10)
```

Comment: `User.includes(:tasks).where("tasks.id IS NOT NULL")` should do what you need

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that Mongoid's [`has_many`](http://mongoid.org/en/mongoid/docs/relations.html#has_many) doesn't leave anything in the parent document so there are no queries on the parent document that will do anything useful for you. However, the `belongs_to :user` in your `Task` will add a `:user_id` field to the `tasks` collection. That leaves you with horrific things like this:

```
user_ids = Task.all.distinct(:user_id)
users    = User.where(:id => user_ids).limit(10)
```

Of course, if you had [`embeds_many :tasks`](http://mongoid.org/en/mongoid/docs/relations.html#embeds_many) instead of `has_many :tasks` then you could query the `:tasks` inside the `users` collection as you want to. OTOH, this would probably break other things.

If you need to keep the tasks separate (i.e. not embedded) then you could set up a counter in `User` to keep track of the number of tasks and then you could say things like:

```
User.where(:num_tasks.gt => 0).limit(10)
```

Comment: Thanks. Can be a performance problem. But I guess I have no another option.

Comment: Caching a counter is quite common with MongoDB. You'll probably find that your schema in MongoDB is more tightly coupled to the specific queries you use than with a relational system. You might also find yourself working a lot harder to manage your data with all the caching and denormalization.

Answer (score 0):

You can do

```
User.where(:tasks.exists => true).limit(10)
```

Update:

Worked for me when doing:

```
u = User.new
t = u.tasks.build
t.save
u.save

u = User.new
u.save

User.where(:tasks.exists => true).limit(10).count
=> 1
```

Comment: Thanks, but it gives me 0, although I have some users with tasks.

Comment: Weird, it worked for me.. Can you please show how you build your objects ?

Comment: `Task.update_attributes(:user_id => user.id)` and also `user.tasks << Task.create!(...)`

Comment: How do you build them?