# How to retrieve records with at least one associated document?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, mongoid

Let's say we have following models:

```
class Provider
  include Mongoid::Document
  has_many :opinions
end

class Opinion
  include Mongoid::Document
  belongs_to :provider
end
```

How I can create scope which will retrieve all Provider object which has at least one associated `Opinion` document ?

Comment: I had the same problem. See the answer I got: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21265578

Answer (score 0):

Something along:

```
scope :with_opinion ->() { where(:_id.in => Opinion.all.where(:provider_id.ne => nil).distinct(:provider_id).pluck(:provider_id)) }
```